# Rpi service fails randomly

Tags: raspberry-pi4

After a few days, I had a service running that logs my internet speeds and hosts a webserver. This was all fine until suddenly it wasn't working / starting anymore.

It says the following in the logs

```
Apr 08 19:26:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Host Internet Stats and log them.
Apr 08 19:26:11 raspberrypi bash[761]: /usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot execute binary file
Apr 08 19:26:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: netcheck.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a
Apr 08 19:26:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: netcheck.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I looked at the code, it worked fine and even runs if I do it manually! I'm have never had this happen before, can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is my service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Host Internet Stats and log them
After=network.target
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/netutils/netutility

ExecStart=/bin/bash sudo python3 Main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! (1) Why do you run bash at all? (2) I’m not sure you can run sudo from a service like that. If the program must be run as root, then register the service for the root user. (3) Where is `Main.py` located? You most probably need to write an absolute path here.

Comment: Main.py is located in /home/pi/netutils/netutility

Comment: My bad. I missed your WorkingDirectory line. Anyway, my best guess would be that trying to run `sudo` fails. Perhaps systemd is running the service as a user that is not allowed to run `sudo` without typing the root password?

Comment: Maybe, but what's weird is that it ran perfectly today this morning, and suddenly this happened